# Java - Incorrect output for response JSON in unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am testing my depositUserBalance endpoint controller and this is just a simple test but I am not sure why it is not getting the correct response JSON as compared to the one returned in my REST API.

```java
// My Controller
@PutMapping("/api/deposit")
public ResponseEntity<UserAmountDTO> depositUserBalance(HttpServletRequest request,
                @RequestBody UserAmountDTO userAmountDTO) {
        Integer userId = (Integer) request.getAttribute("userId");
        userAmountDTO = userService.updateUserBalance(userId, userAmountDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userAmountDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```java
// My UserAmountDTO Data Transfer Object
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserAmountDTO {
    
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public double amount;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    public double balance;

}
```

```java
@Test
public void Test_DepositUserBalance() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    UserAmountDTO userAmountDTO = new UserAmountDTO(2000.0, 3000.0);
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    when(request.getAttribute("userId")).thenReturn(1);
    when(userService.updateUserBalance(1, userAmountDTO)).thenReturn(userAmountDTO);
    String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userAmountDTO);
    System.out.println("requestBody: " + requestBody);

    // Act
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(put(DEPOSIT_PATH)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestBody).with(requestBuilder -> {
                requestBuilder.setAttribute("userId", 1);
                return requestBuilder;
            }))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    // Assert
    int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
    String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    String expectedJson = String.format("{\"balance\":%.1f}", 3000.0);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), status);
    assertEquals(expectedJson, content);
}
```

In my unit test, the requestBody was returned as balance here `requestBody: {"balance":3000.0}` when it should be amount because I set the `@JsonProperty(acccess = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` to amount.

The error from the test was `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: [{"balance":3000.0}] but was: []`. Why is it an empty string? When I tried it in the REST API on POSTMAN, it actually returned me this JSON balance amount. Coupled with the fact that I added `@JsonProperty(acccess = Access.READ_ONLY)` to balance.

Comment: Maybe it is because you are not mocking it correctly: instead of: `when(userService.updateUserBalance(1, userAmountDTO)).thenReturn(userAmountDTO);` try: `when(userService.updateUserBalance(eq(1), eq(userAmountDTO))).thenReturn(userAmountDTO);` Notice that I used `eq()` method from `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq` if that is the case I will put an answer for you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hey Jorge, I am still receiving the same error and the requestBody is still `{"balance":3000.0}` after using the `eq()` method. I agree that I am not mocking it properly too but not sure what the issue is.

Comment: oook, I think I have an idea what might be the problem. So you are mocking your `userService` expecting it to match the specific instance you created in your test of `userAmountDTO` but that is not the case, since that instance is created by the de-serializer on the request. Is is something like: in your unit test `userAmountDTO` instance id is 1 (because you created it on the test) and in your controller the `userAmountDTO` was created by the de-serializer therefore the instance id will be something else resulting in the mock not returning the expected value. Let me think for a bit...

Comment: Another thing, can you debug your controller to see what exactly is it receiving as `userAmountDTO` since you annotated your `balance` as READ_ONLY it is possible that when receiving it there the de-serializer is removing it

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hey I did the debugging as you told me to! I added this in my controller `userAmountDTO = userService.updateUserBalance(userId, userAmountDTO); System.out.println(userAmountDTO.getAmount() + userAmountDTO.getBalance());` and it shows that the userAmount is null after calling `userService.updateUserBalance` in my controller. Do you know how I can get this to work? If you managed to help me I will definitely give you an upvote and accept your answer :)

Comment: I did another debug print by adding `System.out.println(userAmountDTO.getAmount() + userAmountDTO.getBalance());` before `userAmountDTO = userService.updateUserBalance(userId, userAmountDTO);` in my controller and it shows that balance and amount are 0.0 which shouldn't be the case since I mocked them to be 3000.0 and 2000.0 respectively.

Comment: Hi there, for the first one I think the problem is related to those annotations, try removing then to see what happens. For the second it is exactly what I mentioned before, the instance you mocked is not the same as the one that ends up in your controller.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think the problem lies with the second issue, but I am not sure how to solve it. When I removed the check for JSON response body, it did return me a status of 201 which means it passed but the response body is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE ON UNIT TESTING POST REQUEST ON RESTCONTROLLER**

I managed to resolve the mistake and in summary it is because I was passing in an object to the mocked service a different memory address. To put it simply, `when(userService.updateUserBalance(1, userAmountDTO)).thenReturn(userAmountDTO);`, this is an appropriate way to mock the userService.updateUserBalance method.

**However,** inside the `@Test`, the userAmountDTO memory address could be something like @21835tj3. In my controller, `userAmountDTO = userService.updateUserBalance(userId, userAmountDTO);`, the memory address of userAmountDTO being passed into the `userService.updateUserBalance` method could be different like @21943jf3 which was why it does not match the mocked service arguments in the unit test. Objects with the same fields and values doesn't mean they share the same reference, thus the mocked method did not return the expected value.

**To fix this**:

Use the `ArgumentMatchers.any()` Mockito  to match any object of the `UserAmountDTO` class. So, change the mocked method in the unit test to `when(userService.updateUserBalance(eq(1), ArgumentMatchers.any(UserAmountDTO))).thenReturn(userAmountDTO);`

This usually happens with POST requests as we pass in a deserialized JSON object. Also thanks to @JorgeCampos for supporting with the debug process.